# HttpContext receber parâmetro de jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Estou tendo uma dificuldade em receber um parâmetro de um formulário de cadastro para um .ashx.

Trata-se de um formulário simples que receberá dados cadastrais e fará o upload de um currículo. O script do upload eu baixei da net e está usando jQuery/Ajax e c#/HttpHandler.

Segue os códigos:

```
public class file_to_up : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            if (context.Request.QueryString["upload"] != null)
            {
                string pathrefer = context.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
                string Serverpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("credenciamento\\uploads\\");

                var postedFile = context.Request.Files[0];

                string file;

                //For IE to get file name
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE")
                {
                    string[] files = postedFile.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                    file = files[files.Length - 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    file = postedFile.FileName;
                }


                if (!Directory.Exists(Serverpath))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Serverpath);

                string fileDirectory = Serverpath;
                if (context.Request.QueryString["fileName"] != null)
                {
                    file = context.Request.QueryString["fileName"];
                    if (File.Exists(fileDirectory + "\\" + file))
                    {
                        File.Delete(fileDirectory + "\\" + file);
                    }
                }

                string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileDirectory + "\\" + file);
                file = Guid.NewGuid() + ext;

                fileDirectory = Serverpath + "\\" + file;

                postedFile.SaveAs(fileDirectory);

                context.Response.AddHeader("Vary", "Accept");
                try
                {
                    if (context.Request["HTTP_ACCEPT"].Contains("application/json"))
                        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                    else
                        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                }
                catch
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                }

                context.Response.Write("Success");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            context.Response.Write(exp.Message);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
$('#btnFileUpload').fileupload({
    url: 'file-to-up.ashx?upload=start',
    add: function (e, data) {
        console.log('add', data);
        $('#progressbar').show();
        data.submit();
    },
    progress: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progressbar div').css('width', progress + '%');
    },
    success: function (response, status) {
        $('#progressbar').hide();
        $('#progressbar div').css('width', '0%');
        console.log('success', response);
        alert('Enviado');
    },
    error: function (error) {
        $('#progressbar').hide();
        $('#progressbar div').css('width', '0%');
        console.log('error', error);
        alert('Ocorreu um erro e o arquivo não pode ser enviado. Tente novamente');
    }
});
});
```

Gostaria que o nome do  arquivo que atualmente recebe um **Guid** `file = Guid.NewGuid() + ext;` recebesse o número do CPF do candidato...
Claro que você pode questionar.. Oras.. o Guid é perfeito, pois nunca haverá a possibilidade de conflitos.. por que então usar CPF?
Primeiro que não será cumulativo os cadastros e também  porque necessito vincular o arquivo ao CPF dele para ser apreciado pelo gerente que examina os currículos..

Já perdi alguns cabelos tentando mas não consegui.. Alguém poderia dá um help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

e se vc colocar

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnFileUpload').fileupload({
        //incluir o CPF no query string....
        url: 'file-to-up.ashx?upload=start&cpf='+$('#ID_DO_FIELD_CPF').val(),
        //restante do seu código....
    });
});
```

e no no arquivo que trata o upload, vc recebe o paramtero e muda o nome do arquivo......

```
//veja que a query string é a mesma do arquivo js....
var cpf= context.Request.QueryString["cpf"];

//com esta variavel vc altera o nome do arquivo...
file = cpf + ext;
```

Pontos que vc deve levar em consideração

1. Criar um função para remover pontos e traços do cpf
2. Verificar se está ou não preenchido antes de iniciar o upload, isso pode ser um problema, vc vai obrigar o cara a preencher o CPF antes de fazer o upload
3. fazer a verificação de criação pois um cara pode desistir de tudo mesmo enviando o arquivo por ajax

espero ter ajudado....

Comment: sua resposta ajudou sim! Era disto que estava precisando. AS verificações sugeridas já haviam sido feitas. Vlw!!